# Not found bin/sh Docker Image

Tags: r, linux, docker, ubuntu, shiny

I am trying to deploy my Shiny app on my own server, but I cannot solve this issue. This is my docker image

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse

## App folder
WORKDIR /home/admin/shinyAppCovid/

ADD /shinyApp /shinyApp/
ADD /dependencias.txt  /usr/local/bin/


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev

# expose port
EXPOSE 8080

# Download and install library
RUN R -e 'install.packages(read.csv("/usr/local/bin/dependencias.txt")[,1], depencencies=TRUE, repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")'


# run app on container start
CMD ['/usr/bin/R', "-e", "shiny::runApp("/shinyApp/shiny", host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8080)"]
```

The problem is that when i a try to run a container this is what i have

```
/bin/sh: 1: [/usr/bin/R,: not found
```

I changed the last line for jus R and is not working I am still having the same issue, How can I do?

Comment: In the `CMD` line, make sure all of the quotes are `"double quotes"`, for example around the `/usr/bin/R` command.

Comment: Your `CMD` list is **broken**: you quote and unquote and quote and unquote within the same element: `"shiny::runApp("/shinyApp/shiny", host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8080)"`. I suggest you change it to `"shiny::runApp('/shinyApp/shiny', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8080)"`.

Comment: Yes thank you! Now is working